# Trisecting $2\pi/5$, is this possible?

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory

I guess that the answer is no, even knowing that $cos(2\pi/5)$ is constructible since the $5$th root o unity is construtctible.

But when I use the trick for finding the minimal polynomial of $3\theta=2\pi/5$ I get that $\theta$ is the root of

$p(x)=4x^3 - 3x - cos(2\pi/5)$

and this polynomial is not even on $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, so how shoul i proceed to prove that is it or isn't possible to trisect $\theta?$

Comment: Hint: if $a$ and $b$ are constructible then so is $a+b$

Comment: see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentadecagon#Construction) for a construction of regular pentadecagon using compass and ruler.

Comment: $\cos(2\pi/5)$ is a number, not an angle, so "trisecting" it makes no sense. I think you mean to ask whether you can trisect $2\pi/5$ angle (using, presumably, unmarked straightedge and compass). But look: you know you can construct a pentagon; having constructed a pentagon, construct an equilateral triangle sharing a vertex with that pentagon, and voila! a $2\pi/5$ angle.

Comment: What Gerry Myerson said in different words:
$$\frac{2\pi}{15}=\frac{5\pi-3\pi}{15}=\frac{\pi}3-\frac{\pi}5.$$ So if you can construct $2\pi/5$ and $2\pi/3$ (and know how to bisect angles)...

Answer (score 1):

The minimal polynomial for an $n$-th root of unity has degree $\phi(n)$ and the field has an abelian Galois group. The real subfield containing $y=2\cos(2\pi/n)$ has degree $\phi(n)/2$ is also abelian. Hence since $\phi(15)/2=4$ the field generated by $y$ is constructible. (In fact, the minimal polynomial for $y$ is $y^4-y^3-4y^2+4y+1$.)